# Get selected fields on a list using a LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-query-syntax

I have an entity framework generated class like this.

```
public partial class TBLM_PRODUCT
{
    public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_DESC { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_ISBN { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_SUPPLIER { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_PROGROUP { get; set; }
}
```

Normally I select items list like this using a LINQ query.

```
using ( AEntities RAEntity = new AEntities())
{
    RAEntity.TBLM_PRODUCT.ToList<DataControllers.TBLM_PRODUCT>();
}
```

I want to select an item list with two fields like this like as in following query

```
 select PRODUCT_CODE,PRODUCT_DESC from TBLM_PRODUCT where PRODUCT_PROGROUP='GG';
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
using ( AEntities RAEntity = new AEntities())
{
    var all = RAEntity.TBLM_PRODUCT.ToList<DataControllers.TBLM_PRODUCT>();
    var yourList = all
        .Where(x => x.PRODUCT_PROGROUP == "GG")
        .Select(p => new { p.PRODUCT_CODE, p.PRODUCT_DESC })
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't select all records first and then filtered your data.

If you use `.ToList<DataControllers.TBLM_PRODUCT>()` then it can select all records. So instead of this you can select your columns at the time of query fired to database.

If your `TBLM_PRODUCT` is of any collection type like `IEnumerable<>` or `IQueryable<>` then,

```
using ( AEntities RAEntity = new AEntities())
{
    var result = RAEntity.TBLM_PRODUCT.Where(x => x.PRODUCT_PROGROUP == "GG").Select(x => new { x.PRODUCT_CODE, x.PRODUCT_DESC }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (AEntities RAEntity = new AEntities())
{
    var list= RAEntity.TBLM_PRODUCT
        .Where(p => p.PRODUCT_PROGROUP == "GG")
        .Select(p => new TBLM_PRODUCT { PRODUCT_CODE = p.PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_DESC = p.PRODUCT_DESC })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Could you comment and explain your answer, so that other users can understand it better?